# How to wrap two dynamically created elements with span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I need to create two elements `<img>` and `<i>` and wrap it with `div` element:

```
$('<img>', {
  src: 'images/bank-507-logo.png',
  id: "selected_" + selectedBank
})

$('<i>', {
  class: 'fa fa-inr'
})
```

I have code to wrap a single element like:

```
$('<img>', {
  src: 'images/bank-507-logo.png',
  id: "selected_" + selectedBank
}).wrapAll('<span/>');
```

But I need to wrap both `<img>` and `<i>` with that `span` element.

Comment: your title says `div` and in the post you say `span`... decide.

Comment: modified please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery**

```
var span= $('<img>', {
        src: 'images/bank-507-logo.png',
        id: "selected_"+"selectedBank"
  }).add($('<i>', {
        class: 'fa fa-inr'
})).appendTo($('body')).wrapAll($('<span></span>'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/hc0pw1sp/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a common class and then wrap:

```
$('<img>', {
        src: 'images/bank-507-logo.png',
        id: "selected_"+selectedBank,
        'class': 'common'
    })

    $('<i>', {
        'class': 'fa fa-inr common'
    })
$('.common').wrapAll('<span />');
```